# Concatenating rows into columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns, car and color

```
**car**     **color**
audi        brown
benz        black
lambo       white
audi        white
benz        red
audi        grey
```

and now, i want the schema after query such as the car followed by the list of colors
like

```
CAR      COLOR
audi     brown,white,grey
benz     black,red
lambo    white
```

How do i proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
select 
car,
group_concat(color) as color
from table_name
group by car
```